# some videos don't work with matlab with the next error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, detection, matlab-cvst

I am using matlab to detect faces.

Unfortunately, some videos don't work. It gives me the following error

> Attempted to access bbox(1,:); index out of bounds because
>   size(bbox)=[0,4].
>
> Error in tracking (line 13) faceImage    =
>   imcrop(videoFrame,bbox(1,:));

Comment: Consider adding code example which cause the situation you have described. Please state the question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your face detector could not find any face for the specific frame `videoFrame`: the bounding box you got (`bbox`) is empty:

> `size(bbox)=[0,4]`

You might want to add a condition before cropping that `numel(bbox) > 0`.